# Can arc consistency checks be avoided if constraints are formulated properly?

Tags: constraint-satisfaction

While solving a few CSPs by hand, I noticed that I don't actually need to check for arc consistency after each assignment.
All I needed to do was to formulate the CSP in such a way that I'm adding extra constraints based on the nature of initial constraints in an attempt to predict arc inconsistency.

After assigning a value to a given variable, I would do forward checking and that's it.
Unassigned variables are guaranteed to remain arc consistent with each other without the need to run a separate algorithm like MAC-3 or whatnot to purge remaining values.

Has anyone heard of such a thing before? I can't seem to find it in the literature.  feel like I should give an example so let's say variable C has to be greater than variable B and B has to be greater than A. You could either leave it at that and run into arc inconsistency down the road or add an extra constraint stating by inference that C necessarily has to be greater than A, then you don't need a separate arc consistency algorithm. All you need is proper forward checking.

Please let me know if I'm completely wrong about this intuition.

Comment: Could you expand your core question? Do you mean something like http://cse.unl.edu/~choueiry/Documents/Bennaceur-Affane-partition-k-ac.pdf or http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fbacchus/Papers/efc.pdf or want to know whether checks could be removed to change arc consistency? Have you tried to look for a proof? "Has anyone heard of such thing?" is not well defined question, it would be better to tell what you want to save (e.g. computational cost).

Comment: In a nutshell, I am wondering if forward checking can be extended to the point where you don't need arc consistency algorithms such as AC-3 anymore to prune inconsistent values from the domains of uninstantiated variables because such values would have already been taken care of by extensive forward checking.